# SVG Height Larger in Safari

Tags: google-chrome, svg, safari, webkit

Been working on a [site](http://l-indesign.nl/martindijkstra/) for quite a while and almost have it done. I am now mainly dealing with an SVG issue in Safari & Chrome (webkit based browsers). When I load the SVG on the homepage there it is larger than in Firefox and IE. This causes the image (head of the hat man) to slightly be cut off or hidden as it is displayed as larger image than in Firefox for example.
Safari screenshot:

[image: SVG In Safari 6.0.5]

Firefox screenshot:

[image: SVG In Firefox 22]

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570917/svg-height-incorrectly-calculated-in-webkit-browsers) on SO. There they suggested to use:

```
svg { max-height: 100%; }
```

This CSS change as it is on the site:

```
.hatman {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 50px;
    right: 30%;
}

.hatman .hatman-slide {
    height: 100%;
    max-height:100%;/*added as suggested */
    width: 100%;
}
.hatman #profile {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    }
.hatman #hat {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

That did however not work for me. The answer was not accepted by the OP either. Another similar issues is described at SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442917/webkit-doesnt-render-svg-in-auto-sized-container), but no answer yet either. Has anyone a suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: *sidenote:* `right: 30%;` in `.hatman` has no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this was more an issue with Webkit dealing with the SVG resizing.

This JavaScript was used to fix the max height issue

```
    function TSafariFix() {

    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    TSafariFix_Resize();
    });
    TSafariFix_Resize();
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    Hatman = new THatman();
    SFix = new TSafariFix();
});
```