# SVG : I need an SVG file that reads 'TEST' and auto-expands 100%

Tags: html, css, svg, gimp, inkscape

This is the file i have.

```
<svg
   width="700"
   height="500">
  <g
     id="layer1">
    <text
       style="font-size:100%;font-family:Bitstream Vera Sans"
       x="6"
       y="37"
       id="">TEST</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

i want `TEST` to automatically occupy the whole thing somehow. 
like 100% kind of a thing.

right now the text is miss-alligned due to x and y ordinates.

Comment: What do you mean by auto expands? height="100%" width="100%" or something else?

Comment: width and height auto, to fit surrounding div?

Comment: is it possible to have text filling up the entire SVG file ? that way text does not have to have a dimension.. all that matters is the size of the svg file . ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [setting the `viewBox`](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/bDHGs/) instead of a specific width and height:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 240 70">
  <g id="layer1">
    <text
       style="font-size:100px;font-family:Bitstream Vera Sans"
       x="0"
       y="70"
       id="">TEST</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Note that [Chrome has some rendering inconsistencies with SVG with no specific height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12631326/8655).